# How to add java code from eclipse to git repository

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket-server

I am on a windows machine and my .java files are stored on my disk (C:\Users\myname\workspace..etc)

I have a git repository set up in a cloud and I SSH to it using putty.

My question is, how do I add the files in my workspace to the repository?

When I do `git add filename.java` the linux terminal says it cannot find specified file.

So do I some how bring the the copies of the java files into this terminal directory?

Btw I'm using an Atlassian Stash on Amazon Web Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  current working directory to your local project and run following commands:

**Step 1 :** Initializes a new Git repository. Until you run this command inside a repository or directory, it’s just a regular folder. Only after you input this does it accept further Git commands.

```
git init
```

**Step 2 :** This does not add new files to your repository. Instead, it brings new files to Git’s attention. After you add files, they’re included in Git’s “snapshots” of the repository.

```
git add .
```

**Step 3:**  Check the status of your repository. See which files are inside it, which changes still need to be committed, and which branch of the repository you’re currently working on.

```
git status
```

**Step 4:** Git’s most important command. After you make any sort of change, you input this in order to take a “snapshot” of the repository. Usually it goes git commit -m **“Message here.”** The -m indicates that the following section of the command should be read as a message.

```
git commit -m "Committing Files - Message"
```

**Step 5:** Add origin to the **.gitconfig** file.

```
git remote add origin <url to your git repo.git>
```

**Step 6:** Push the changes from your local repository.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Where do I invoke init git command? Its through the DOS terminal and I should go to that  folder in my eclipse workspace?

Comment: Yes, inside your project too in parallel to your java src folder.

Comment: ahh ok thanks. So doing git init in a directory in my workspace will turn that directory into a repository. So in my case I would do it in the Java src folder. Now, will running git init affect my java code at all? I mean will it alter anything for the program's execution?

Comment: No it will not affect anything, run the `git init` in folder which you want to push on remote, it depends on you if you want to push java src folder alone or any other folder along with it.

Comment: yes, I want to push all my folders inside the java src folder. If I push it will the folders no longer be in the workspace on my disk?

Comment: It remains in your disk also, nothing will be happening to your code on disk as well. Go to `src` folder and start running commands.